# How to prove that from $x_k \rightarrow x$, $y_k \longrightarrow y$ and $y_k^Tx_k \le b$ follows $y^Tx \le b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Consider the map $A: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $A(x) := \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n: y^Tx \le b, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Is $A$ closed?

Here is the definition of "closed" that we use in the lecture:

> **Closed map:** Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be both non-empty and closed. A map $A: X \longrightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y)$ is called **closed** at $x \in X$ if for all sequences $(x_k)_k$ and $(y_k)_k$ with $x_k \rightarrow x$, $y_k \in A(x_k)$ and $y_k \rightarrow y$ holds $y \in A(x)$. If $A$ is closed in all $x \in X$ we call $A$ **closed**.

I could not find a counterexample, so I suppose that the claim is true. However, I do not see how I could prove this. I tried to start with:

We assume that $x_k \rightarrow x$, $y_k \in A(x_k)$ and $y_k \rightarrow y$. We know that for all $k$ holds $y_k^Tx_k \le b$. If we can show from there that $y^Tx\le b$ we would be done. However, I do not see how to do that. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz tells you that the function $f(x,y)=x\cdot y = x^\top y$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$. Therefore,
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k\cdot y_k = x\cdot y \quad\text{when}\quad x_k\to x \text{ and } y_k\to y.$$
Since $x_k\cdot y_k\le b$ for all $k$, it follows that $\lim
\limits_{k\to\infty} x_k\cdot y_k\le b$, and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

We have $(x_k - x)^T(y_k-y)\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0, $ hence $x_k^Ty_k+x^Ty-x^Ty_k-x_k^Ty\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0.$ But since $\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}x^Ty_k=\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}x_k^Ty=x^Ty, $ we get $\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}} x_k^Ty_k-x^Ty=0.$ Now the result follows by noting that $x^Ty= \underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}} x_k^Ty_k\leq b$.